# replacing values in a column with another column R

Tags: r, replace, multiple-columns

I have two tables in different dimensions, now I want to replace value datA$swl1 with values in datB$swl2 according to userids.

datA

```
 id swl1
 1   0.8
 2   0.7
 3   0.4
 4   0.7
 5   0.0
```

datB

```
id   swl2
 1   0.8
 3   0.6
 5   0.7
```

output

datA (here swl1 is replaced by the new values in swl2, but not all the ids have a new values, for those that haven't, the original values are retained)

```
 id swl1
 1   0.8
 2   0.7
 3   0.6
 4   0.7
 5   0.7
```

how to do this?

Comment: what’s the second column in datB called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `merge` to match by `id`, then replace in column `swl1` those items from `datB` which exist:

```
datC <- merge(datA, datB, all.x=TRUE)
datC
##   id swl1 swl2
## 1  1  0.8  0.8
## 2  2  0.7   NA
## 3  3  0.4  0.6
## 4  4  0.7   NA
## 5  5  0.0  0.7
```

This matches up the rows.  Now to replace those values in column `swl1` with the non-`NA` values from column `swl2`:

```
datC$swl1 <- ifelse(is.na(datC$swl2), datC$swl1, datC$swl2)
datC$swl2 <- NULL
datC
##   id swl1
## 1  1  0.8
## 2  2  0.7
## 3  3  0.6
## 4  4  0.7
## 5  5  0.7
```

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain this result with one line of code:

```
datA$swl1[datA$id %in% datB$id] <- datB$swl2
#> datA
#  id swl1
#1  1  0.8
#2  2  0.7
#3  3  0.6
#4  4  0.7
#5  5  0.7
```

With the `%in%` operator we select the entries of the column `datA$swl1` that belong to rows with the same `id` as those listed in `datB`. These values in the column of `datA$swl1` are then replaced with the entries of the `swl2` column of `datB`.

Comment: %in% is quite useful!

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, using [`data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
require(data.table)
setDT(datA)[datB, swl1 := swl2, on = "id"]
```

`datA` is updated by reference.

Comment: This worked for me. One feature of this approach is that any NA values in swl2 will be copied over to swl1. This was a positive for me as I wanted to retain the NA values.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to select the largest value, regardless of which column it is in, you could try

```
library(dplyr)
datA <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), swl1=c(0.8, 0.7, 0.4, 0.7, 0.0))
datB <- data.frame(id=c(1,3,5), somename=c(0.8, 0.6, 0.7))

datC <- full_join(datA, datB)
datA <- data.frame(id=c(1:5))    
datA$swli1 <- apply(datC[, c('swl1', 'somename')], 1, function(x) max(na.omit(x)))

> datA
  id swli1
1  1   0.8
2  2   0.7
3  3   0.6
4  4   0.7
5  5   0.7
```

Comment: Helpful code for this sort of thing:  `datA <- read.table(header=TRUE, file='clipboard')`

Comment: But then the answer is not a self-contained solution

Comment: You can make it self-contained by providing the data via `dput` -- or even editing the question and putting the definitions there.  Just trying to save you some time.