# Replacing some values in a column according to another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm struggling to replace some of the values in a column in R. In my dataframe, there are more than 100000 rows; however, I'm simplifying things here. Let's consider this imaginary data frame:

```
ID<-c("Rick","Anna","Sarah","Mike","Kim","Garrett","Tom")
Age<-c(31,23,26,43,32,41,22)
df1<-cbind(ID,Age)

ID        Age

Rick      31
Anna      23
Sarah     26
Mike      43
Kim       32
Garrett   41
Tom       22
```

However, some of age information in this data frame is wrong and df2 has the correct information for age.

```
ID<-c("Rick","Tom")
Age<-c(35,23)
df2<-cbind(ID,Age)

ID      Age
Rick    35
Tom     23
```

My question is, how can I take the correct values in df2 and supply them to df1?

I have tried the solutions in other similar situations on stackoverflow including:

```
df1$Age<-df2$Age[df1$ID %in% df2$ID]
df1$Age<-df2$Age[match(df1$ID, df2$ID]
```

These codes take the values in df2 and returns NAs for IDs that are not available in df2.

I need suggestions, please.

Comment: The solution presented in the suggested link doesn't apply to my problem. I still need suggestions.

Comment: I have found the answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239581/replacing-values-in-a-column-with-another-column-r